# jquery iterator in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, iterator

I am new in JavaScript and jQuery. I have found a problem which I can't solve myself.

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    $("#c" + i).on("click", function () { alert(i) });
}
```

It attaches events to every element with id from c0 to c11 with alert(12) instead of alert(i)...

On the other hand

```
$("#c0").on("click", function () { alert(0) });
$("#c1").on("click", function () { alert(1) });
$("#c2").on("click", function () { alert(2) });
...
```

Works good. Isn't it the same?

Comment: You are alerting `i`. When the click would happen, loop has already finished and so `i` is set to `12`

Comment: instead of `id` you can use class name config to handle the click event

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way `var` keyword works and also because

```
$("#c" + i).on("click", function () { alert(i) });`
```

is async in nature.

just do this instead,

**Quick Fix**

```
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++)
 {
   $("#c" + i).on("click", function () { alert(i) });
 }
```

Explanation: Your code does not work because `$('#c').on('click', fun)` is async in nature what that means is this function `function () { alert(i) }` will be executed later in time, by the time that happens your for loop will be finished with the value of `i = 12` hence, you are getting 12 as a value for all handlers.

Now the question is **how adding `let` fixed this**?

The answer is simple, `Let` follows Block scoping whereas `var` or no var ( global ) is not blocked scoped. `var` has a functional scope and to achive the same with `var` you'll need to do something like this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    $("#c" + i).on("click", function () { alert(i) });
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm!
So it's all about "cloning" the value from iterator.
Sorry, looks like rookie mistake, but it's my second day in JS, and I wasn't able to find solution here and on google :)

Comment: “async in nature”? That’s a confusing way of saying that the function is run at a later point in time where the function-scoped `var` has already changed. After all, you wouldn’t call `let` “synchronous in nature”, would you? The issue is _just_ the `var`.

Comment: @Xufox I agree that was a confusing way of saying it. I have fixed it though.